# SQL Server 2005 : map Transaction_ID to @@SPID

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there anyway to map `transaction_id` from somewhere like `sys.dm_tran_active_transactions`to an `SPID` in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: [`sys.dm_tran_session_transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188739(v=sql.90).aspx)?

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Thanks. Do you want to put it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may sound obvious, but the first two columns documented for [`sys.dm_tran_session_transactions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188739%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) are `session_id` and `transaction_id`. This is the table that maps between transactions and sessions.

Comment: Thanks again. New it had to be there somewhere