# The table sys.dm_tran_session_transactions is always empty

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration, system-views

Hello whenever I select in a new query from the system view **sys.dm_tran_session_transactions** I get always 0 rows

```
select * from sys.dm_tran_session_transactions
```

But people on some other answers use this table.

[SQL Server 2005 : map Transaction_ID to @@SPID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703549/sql-server-2005-map-transaction-id-to-spid)

Why have I empty this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sys.dm_tran_session_transactions` DMV will return sessions with open transactions so it seems there were no such sessions when you ran the query. Start a transaction to see the an example of data returned:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions;
ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: A bit strange that is needed as a `SELECT` running in auto commit mode is already a transaction and is returned from `sys.dm_tran_current_transaction` and `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions` https://i.stack.imgur.com/65nJd.png

Comment: @MartinSmith, yes, the exact meaning of transaction depends on the context. Another ambiguity is with regards to a snapshot isolation level transaction. One might assume the snapshot view of data starts with the `BEGIN TRAN` but in practice it begins with the first query within that explict transaction.